# charging electric car battery through road - grounding?

Tags: battery-charging, connector, grounding

Alright then, hi all.

For a Mobility Design Master Thesis Project I want to charge an EV battery through the road while driving.

*I just can't get to grips with this. I'm slightly frustrated, don't bash on me if the question is stupid (again). I tried understanding some similar questions, but they seem to tell that I need a ground connection. I didn't find an answer to my questions, or I was to stewpid to filter out what I need to know :D)).*

How many contacts do I need? Aren't 2 enough? Does it need to be grounded? Does the ground connection have to be a "proper connection"? Or is a grounding strap enough? Do I even need this ####? Isn't the chassis enough grounding anyway? Cars don't need extra grounding on the ride, do they? So why extra grounding for charging???

How do [these guys](http://www.fabric-project.eu/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&layout=category&task=category&id=45&Itemid=259) get along with 2 contacts? (basically what I want to do)
Does it have anyting to do with DC? Is it possible with DC? How about AC?

*Long story short: Do I need an external ground connection? What would be a "proper" ground connection? Do I need 3 connectors to the road?*

Comment: Start by learning what a ground connection does and when it is needed. I could just answer yes/no you need it or not but this is **your** project/Thesis so **you** should know. You can't just write: *I use this and that because some guy on Stack Exchange EE said I should*, now can you? You just have too many basic questions. We're not here to educate you to the level needed for doing your project.

Comment: Me thinks your are confusing "ground" connection, with connection to the ground. The Volvo truck is connecting to power rails buried in the ground. That is not the same thing at all.

Comment: FYI: "ground" has more than one meaning in electronics design.  http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/11BE00780D41622686256BE5006F04CF

Comment: And Volvo used 750V DC in their track. One will be positive, the other electrical ground. Which does raise the interesting question of what happens when the truck tries to go the other way.

Comment: I'm struggling with the concept of someone getting a master's thesis in EE without being able to answer this question!

Comment: @pjc50 actually the more I think about it, he has a point. Electric trams etc, the ground is the rails, it doesn not matter which way the train is pointing. Two rails on the road, direction matters.

Comment: Though I guess if you look close they actually have four rails and two pickups. I suppose the pantograph only picks up on the "driver's side" or "passenger side" rails.

Comment: I don't feel like we have enough information about your premise to answer this, anyway... Are you talking about a tram system that would allow EV cars to charge while on that road if they have your product, or an EV car that charges by taking energy from the Earth/friction? Are you talking about Ground as a 0 point for your charging, or an emergency Ground (as you'd have in High V such as Electrical work)?

Comment: I'm a Designer student, not an electric engineer student. My knowledge of electricity is therefore very limited. I just need to know the package. What do I need for this to work (in theory).

Comment: Damn.  That system looks like a recipe for dead pedestrians.  Two exposed rails in the road at 750VDC and enough current to accelerate a car to 100kph in just a few hundred meters.

Comment: @JRE.. there is a lot of that kind of technological "advancements" going on these days...... most of them half baked ideas if you ask me.

Comment: I think what I'm talking about is ground as a 0 point. the one that is needed in an EV charging cable.

Comment: @Dmitri  see my comments. You only need 2 contacts. Making sure they are the right way round needs 3 or 4 rails. As for the safety ground, the integrity of that is questionable.

Comment: @Trevor: Do I also only need 2 contacts for AC?

Comment: You always need at least two.

Comment: Paris (France) once experimented with a tram system that used studs set into the road and made live by a magnet built into the pickup skate. It failed because of sticking relay contacts (This in the days before semiconductors), but **might** be the sort of thing that could be made to work now.

Comment: @DanMills Link maybe?

Comment: @Dmitri: Can't you do the search yourself rather than have Dan do it for you?

Comment: didn't get far in google, difficult if I don't even understand what he means...
I mean [google search](https://www.google.at/search?ei=LGILWpD2JM3ewALHnJ-oDw&q=paris+experimental+tram+system+studs+set+into+the+road+magnet+built+into+pickup+skate&oq=paris+experimental+tram+system+studs+set+into+the+road+magnet+built+into+pickup+skate&gs_l=psy-ab.3...30263.30942.0.31288.4.4.0.0.0.0.82.319.4.4.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.UYNJ2hDjgmU&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0)

Comment: @Dmitri https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stud_contact_system

Answer (score 5):

[image]

*Figure 1. A popular road-supplied vehicle power system. Source: [SpeedHunters.com](http://www.speedhunters.com/2015/11/finger-on-the-trigger-getting-down-with-scalextric/).*

> How many contacts do I need?

Minimum of two.

> Aren't 2 enough?

Could be if you don't need 3-phase electricity.

> Does it need to be grounded?

Usually, yes, to prevent the supply voltages floating to very high voltages.

Rather than, for example, having a ground (0 V) rail and a 400 V rail the system could be designed with -200 V and +200 V rail with respect to ground. I don't think that anyone touching either would survive.

> Does the ground connection have to be a "proper connection"?

Yes because you will be dealing with high currents.

> Or is a grounding strap enough?

Grounding straps are for static discharge. This involves tiny currents at extremely high voltages.

> Do I even need this ####?

'####' is a term with which I am unfamiliar.

> Isn't the chassis enough grounding anyway? Cars don't need extra grounding on the ride, do they? So why extra grounding for charging???

Because electrical current requires a circuit back to the source and vehicle tyres are insulators.

> How do these guys get along with 2 contacts? (basically what I want to do) Does it have anyting to do with DC? Is it possible with DC? How about AC?

Feed and return. This can be AC or DC.

---

The article you linked to does not address safety. For long lengths of track as shown in the photo high voltages will be required. This has multiple problems:

- Safety for humans and animals.
- Insulation from ground.
- Prevention of leakage current in rain and snow.
- How to charge (financially) for power usage.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to help :)
So, I need 480V, when i use +240V and -240V AC, then I wouldn't need a 0-Ground?
(I think I got something wrong again)

Comment: AC means alternating current. Alternating current means that the sign of the voltage changes at the supply frequency. Therefore + and - are meaningless. For an AC system this could be referred to as split-phase as the two wires would be in anti-phase. I don't know why you think you need 480 V in particular.

Comment: 480V I chose because of the battery charging, I think batteries work with those Volts. Tesla Superchargers use this Volts, for a reason maybe? Probably easier because it doesn't need to be transformed (down from 960V), I guess? I don't know, that's why rather left it as it is.

Comment: "Feed and return" - do you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-wire_transmission_line)?

Comment: No. Read the theory section. It's not practical. I'm sorry, Dmitri, but you are trying to design a complex system without basic electrical knowledge. This is doomed to failure. You need at least a couple of weeks studying basic circuit theory and DC and AC circuits.

Comment: Well, I'm not an electric engineer student and I'm not writing an EE Thesis. I'm a Design Student. It doesn't need to actually work. I just need to know if and maybe how, basically, in theory, it could be done with 2 contacts. The engineering is not part of my study.

Comment: Then just have a positive and negative rail and don't specify the voltages.

Comment: @Dmitri, then what are you designing, without any knowledge of electricals? You need to understand at least something about current, about its amount in EV (which will be quite substantial), so the contacts will be able to conduct it. Therefore they must have sufficient surface, flexibility, shape, etc. What is your "design output", practically speaking?

Comment: Theme: 
Year 2030. Electric vehicles charge dynamically on highways. Li-S batteries. Charging strips every 20km, consisting of individual plates that only activate underneath the cars (safety). Extending EV range to infinity. (range anxiety solved) Charging strips need to deliver up to 768kW power (480V x 1600A, omaybe 960V x 800A). @120km/h = 30s on each strip x 5 per 100km = 25+kWh dynamic charge per 100km. 
I've already put too much calculations into it. But I want some science backing up my theory. I consulted an EE prof, he said it should be fine... Now I'm building the package (basic).

Comment: 768 kW x 30 s = 6.4 kWh. The Nissan Leaf has an 80 kW motor. If it was able to cruise at 50 kW then your recharge (assuming a battery could absorb power that quickly) would last 7.7 minutes. (This assumes 100% efficiency in storage and retrieval.)

Comment: A normal consumption @ 120km/h is ~25kWh/100km (Renault ZOE)